# Cover set of Boolean formulas with conjunctions

Tags: lo.logic, boolean-functions, boolean-formulas, covering-problems

I want to cover a set of Boolean formulas (over the same variables) with disjunctive conjunctions. Here's an example with two formulas $p_1$ and $p_2$ over the set of variables $\{A, B, X, Y\}$:

[image]

I want to partition the solution space into conjunctions and represent all formulas as disjunctions of such conjunctions:

[image]

In the left example, the solution space is partitioned into five conjunctions. Both $p_1$ and $p_2$ can be represented as disjunctions of these conjunctions, as shown. Note that not every conjunction appears in a disjunction. However, it is still needed to partition the solution space.

I am looking for such a partition with the *minimal* number of conjunctions. So although the partition on the right also admits a representation as disjunctions, it consists of six conjunctions and is therefore not minimal.

Is this a solved problem? I am interested in both structural and algorithmic results.

Comment: aren't you just looking for [prime implicants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_implicant#Prime_implicant)?

Comment: @holf It seems like prime implicants are defined for a single formula. I'm looking for a similar concept, but for multiple formulas.

Comment: yeah but then they are the prime implicant of the disjunction of your formulas aren't they?

Comment: @holf Not necessarily, are they? Say you had a third formula $p_3 = (\neg A \land \neg X \land B)$, then $p_2$ would be a prime implicant and $p_3$ is not represented.